# Using UITabBarController but status bar covers view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, statusbar

Quoting from this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html

```
"Applications that use an opaque UINavigationController or UITabBarController automatically keep their content below the status bar."
```

My root view controller is a UITabBarController however when that loads a table view controller the status bar is covering it.
Is this documentation therefore incorrect?

Note I'm not asking about how to solve this issue, there's plenty of questions about that already, I'm asking if the documentation is correct, and if it is they why is my content not below the status bar despite using a UITabBarController.