# Children UIViewControllers of UITabBarController overlapping Status Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

- Xcode 7
- iOS Target 9.3
- Swift 2

I have created a new Tabbed Application in Xcode:

[image]

I changed the background of the first template generated UIViewController super view to gray and then I run the app, as you can see in this screenshot the First UIView is overlapped by the Status Bar:

[image]

I have read many articles, particulary specified to iOS 7 regarding allocating space for the Status Bar.

I also read on [apple.developer.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1797/_index.html) the following quote:

"Applications that use an opaque UINavigationController or UITabBarController automatically keep their content below the status bar."

In general this link on the apple.developer.com website does seem a bit outdated.

But, with that said, I am expecting the UITabBarController to load the tabbed children views with with space allocated for the status as displayed in the Storyboard for the UITabBarController:

[image]

I have tried adding the following to my UITabBarController class:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
}
```

I have looked at many Stackoverflow question and answer threads, I found this person asking the same question on Stackoverflow:
[Using UITabBarController but status bar covers view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416330/using-uitabbarcontroller-but-status-bar-covers-view)

**I do know how to add a constraint to the Top Layout Guide to each parent view in each UiViewController tab but I am trying to avoid adding a new top level UIView because my existing UIViewControllers tabs all have UILabels, UIButtons, UICollections, etc in the SuperView I cannot add a constraint to Top Layout Guide to the SuperView in Xcode Storyboard.**

With the SuperView I cannot add a Top Level Constraint by Control Dragging it seems:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve the look of pre-iOS 7?

Comment: No, I am not trying to achieve a pre-iOS7 app, I am just trying to embrace the UITabBarController space allocated for the status bar in any child tabs, which Apple documentation, referenced in my questions says it will do and the Storyboard picture of the UITabBarController also pictures space for the Status Bar in my screenshot of Xcode in my question

Comment: Okay, I think what they mean by automatically keep their content below the status bar is that the auto layout guide for attaching your content to the view will automatically take the status bar into account. So if you're using it in non-full screen, the content would simply attach to the top of the UIView. However, in this case it is full screen, and so auto-layout automatically provides a vertical layout guide that adds the extra 20 pixels on to keep your content below the status bar. Make sense?

Comment: Yes this makes sense, thanks @SeanCAtkinson, when would an app NOT be full screen?

Comment: It might not be full screen if you add it as child of another view controller. So for example, you might have a UIViewController as your rootViewController of your window. Then create a childView of that view controller with the desired frame to act as a container. Finally add your UITabBarViewController as a childViewController of your original UIViewController and the view of the tabViewcontroller as a child view of the container view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS handles this for you inside of auto layout. Whilst the view extends underneath the status bar, fix your constraints to be 0 distance in the 'Vertical Spacing to top layout guide' constraint and you will find it sits underneath the status bar as expected.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I do know how to add this constraint to each top view in each UiViewController but I am trying to avoid add a new top level view for many my UiViewControlers that are tabs have all UILabels, UIButtons, UICollections, etc in the SuperView which I cannot add constraints to

Comment: You don't need to add another top level view - why can't you add constraints to the items?

Comment: Checkout the updates to my question, I added a picture at the bottom, when I Control Drag I cannot add a Constraint to the Top Layout Guide

Comment: Yes, that is from your superview which is automatically linked to the top of it's superview - the tab bar controller in this case, which sits inside your UIWindow. What exactly is the effect you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Right and the Superview is a child of a UITabBarController which automatically keeps child tabs content below the status bar according to Apple documentation which I referenced in my question

Answer (score 0):

So I found through the help of @SeanCAtkinson that things are working as the should. I needed add a constraint to the Top Layout guide for any UIViewController that was a tab aka a child of my UITabBarController.

I thought any child that was tab would be displayed with spaced allocated for the Status bar. I thought UITabBarController was doing that, based on how it looks in the Xcode 7 Storyboard:

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the UITabBarController implies that tabs will display within the light grey square, which you can see has top "guid" below the status bar.

It just isn't the case the UITabBarController will stop the Status Bar from overlapping children tabs whether UIViewControllers, UICollectionViewControllers or UITableViewControllers, etc. You have to use the Top Layout Guide constraint your children tabs.

What partcularly confusing is that a SuperView cannot have the Top Layout guide contraint, the SuperView will always be full screen.